# Rails I18n Accessing Path Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

Let's say I have a mailer, that is triggered from multiple locations in my app, that uses an I18n key that references an app URI. Like this:

```
mailers:
  congratulations: "Congratulations! Go to https://www.example.com to claim your prize!"
```

Because I access it from multiple locations, I don't want to pass the URI in to the I18n call.

If I have this message in multiple languages, all referencing the same URI, how can I pass a variable of that URI in to the message, like a path helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the URI in application.rb and you can access it as `MyAppName::Application::YOUR_URI`

```
congratulations: "Congratulations! Go to #{MyAppName::Application::YOUR_URI} to claim your prize!"
```

Comment: Yep, that would work. It's not a great place to store the URI, but I see your point. Do you have any ideas for accessing the path helper itself?

Comment: yes, you can access path helpers as `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.ur_path`

Comment: and for url: `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.your_url`